# How to use "cleos push transaction"?

Tags: cleos, transactions

I'd like to make a simple action in the format of `cleos push transaction`.

Motivation:
DApps often need transactions with multiple actions, which can't be done with `cleos push action`.
So the natural learning path to do that is to first do a `cleos push transaction` with a single concrete action, and then learn how to `cleos push transaction` with multiple actions (which will likely be trivial).

---

For example, I can write

```
cleos --url api.eosnewyork.io push action eosio.token transfer '["useraccount1", "useraccount2", "0.0001 EOS", ""]' -p useraccount1@active
```

How do I say exactly the same in the `push transaction` format?

[The example](https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-push-transaction) at what seems to be the official docs is annoyingly empty.

---

My attempt so far is:

```
cleos --url api.eosnewyork.io push transaction '{"actions": [{"account": "eosio.token", "name": "transfer", "authorization": [{"actor": "useraccount1", "permission": "active"}], "data": "{\"from\": \"useraccount1\", \"to\": \"useraccount2\", \"quantity\": \"0.0001 EOS\", \"memo\": \"\"}"}]}' push transaction '{"actions": [{"account": "eosio.token", "name": "transfer", "authorization": [{"actor": "useraccount1", "permission": "active"}], "data": "{\"from\": \"useraccount1\", \"to\": \"useraccount2\", \"quantity\": \"0.0001 EOS\", \"memo\": \"\"}"}]}'
```

To which `cleos` replies `Invalid hex character: {`.
It seems to suggest that the "data" string should be in hexadecimal form.
In desperation, I tried to just [convert](https://ideone.com/NFoU52) the `data` string to hexadecimal (with `"` instead of `\"`), like this:

```
cleos --url api.eosnewyork.io push transaction '{"actions": [{"account": "eosio.token", "name": "transfer", "authorization": [{"actor": "useraccount1", "permission": "active"}], "data": "{\"from\": \"useraccount1\", \"to\": \"useraccount2\", \"quantity\": \"0.0001 EOS\", \"memo\": \"\"}"}]}' push transaction '{"actions": [{"account": "eosio.token", "name": "transfer", "authorization": [{"actor": "useraccount1", "permission": "active"}], "data": "7b2266726f6d223a2022757365726163636f756e7431222c2022746f223a2022757365726163636f756e7432222c20227175616e74697479223a2022302e3030303120454f53222c20226d656d6f223a2022227d"}"}]}'
```

Then the server at api.eosnewyork.io says `Error 3040005: Expired Transaction`, and e.g. the server at api1.eosdublin.io says `Error 3200006: invalid http request`.

Comment: What's wrong with this `cleos --url api.eosnewyork.io push action eosio.token transfer '["useraccount1", "useraccount2", "0.0001 EOS", ""]' -p useraccount1@active`

Comment: @LeiKan That works fine. But dapps often need transactions with multiple actions, which can't be done with `cleos push action`. So I'd like to be able to do `cleos push transaction` with a single concrete action, as the hardest step in learning how to `cleos push transaction` with multiple actions (which seems trivial then). I've added this to the body of the question.

Comment: I haven't try push transaction, but I think you could use `cleos  --print-request --dont-broadcast` to get the transaction json. Then you could submit the transaction json content.

Comment: If your transaction need multiple action at a time you can can handle that with approach  mentioned by Lei Kan.You need to create  a new action and call the actions you want to use simultaneously, So now you need to push only the newly created action.

Comment: @LeiKan yay, this approach was helpful, thanks! Are you interested in writing a full answer? If not, I'll write one myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created text file with the following inside:

```
{
  "actions": [
    {   
      "account": "eosio",
      "name": "newaccount",
      "authorization": [
        {
          "actor": "youraccount",
          "permission": "active",
        }
      ],  
      "data": {
        "creator": "youraccount",
        "name": "yournewaccount",
        "owner": {
          "threshold": 1,
          "keys": [
            {
              "key": "EOS5NH5qF4zS5Z336Djs1xvXjYgWxe47jbrRL6ZCkPgDf6QsfzUrJ",
              "weight": 1,
            }
          ],
          "accounts": [], 
          "waits": [], 
        },
        "active": {
          "threshold": 1,
          "keys": [
            {
              "key": "EOS5NH5qF4zS5Z336Djs1xvXjYgWxe47jbrRL6ZCkPgDf6QsfzUrJ",
              "weight": 1,
            }   
          ],
          "accounts": [], 
          "waits": [], 
        },  
      },  
    },  
  ],  
}
```

and run
`cleos push transaction file.txt`

** Note that you can write multiple actions.

Comment: Glad that it works now, and thanks for the answer! At the time of the question though, data could have been given to `cleos` only in binary (encoded) form.