# Beginner question about signing transaction with cleos

Tags: cleos, transactions

I am new to EOS and having some trouble. I got cleos working and I am connected to one of the api endpoints found [here](https://www.eosdocs.io/resources/apiendpoints/). It's working as far as I know since I am able to get block info. My end goal is to send a transaction to a contract.

First, is my understanding correct that I need to sign and then push the transaction?

Second, when I type `cleos sign help` some things it says I need is

1. transaction TEXT: The JSON string or filename defining the transaction to sign (required)
2. chain-id

As far as the chain-id, is this just the chain-id field of `cleos get info`?

I literally have no clue what the first part is asking for. I can't seem to find any examples anywhere. FWIW, I can get the abi of the contract that I want to interact with (but even that I have no clue what's going on).

Comment: you should use `cleos transfer`

Comment: @confused00 what does that do? Will that let me interact with a contract? Sorry--struggling with finding any type of examples!

Comment: Transfer looks like it's just for sending tokens? https://developers.eos.io/eosio-cleos/reference#cleos-transfer

Comment: is this not the aim? "My end goal is to send a transaction to a contract." you can also push custom actions using `cleos push action`

Comment: Hm. I think I just need to learn the terminology (I'm very familiar with developing in ethereum). What is the difference between signing and transaction and pushing vs transferring? What is an action? If you have a good resource to learn about this stuff, that would be great.

Comment: https://developers.eos.io/

Answer (score 1):

You have not to sign manually.

just

```
cleos push action <contract> <action> '<parameter>' -p <signer>@active
```

for example) user 'leettamna111' want to call action named 'hello' of 'greet' contract with argument 'good day'

```
cleos push action greet hello '["good day"]' -p leettamna111@active
```

Comment: Thanks! So do I get the actions of a contract and what arguments it’s looking for in its ABI? So why do I not have to sign? Will push automatically sign it?

Comment: Yes ABI is used for check Action argument, and Table.
"-p" is part of command which key determine for sign

and, you can pass argument with json(must specify key:value) instead of list structure

Answer (score 0):

If you need to push multiple actions into one transaction, look at my [answer](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/4912/2951) .